# Maximizing a number and 0 in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df), and one of the columns 'SUM(CONTRACT_NPV)' is made up of numbers. I'm trying to take the max of (#, 0) in each row of the column. So far, i made 'CONTRACT_NPV' equal to a variable 'SUM' and then attempted this code:

```
df['NUM'] = SUM[SUM >= 0]
```

This worked for me in the past when I wanted to take the max of each number and then sum it, but I took out the .sum() here because I only want to maximize the number in each row, not sum them all together.

However, when I do this, I get a lot of not applicable in my new 'NUM' column I just created. Since I'm simply looking to maximize between the number in the 'A' column and 0, and every row in column 'A' has an actual number in it, I have no idea why my output is not applicable?

I then tried this same code but without the intermediate variable step like so:

```
 df['NUM'] = df['SUM(CONTRACT_NPV)'][df['SUM(CONTRACT_NPV)' >= 0]
 print(df)
```

However, I received an error when I did this saying there's a syntax error right next to print. Thusly, I have no idea what's going on, or what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

```
df['NUM'] = df['SUM(CONTRACT_NPV)'][df['SUM(CONTRACT_NPV)' >= 0]]
```

You were missing an end bracket. If you use a proper code editor, it will catch a lot of these errors for you. VSCode is a pretty descent one

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int() Was given this error, tried this code to turn it into an int: `temp3=str(df8['SUM(CONTRACT_NPV)'])
temp3=temp3.replace(",",'')
int(temp3)`  but that didn't work saying there was an invalid literal for int base 10